# Creating a mysql docker container setting env variables

Tags: java, docker, docker-api, spotify-docker-client

I am using the spotify-docker-client to create and start a mysql container for testing. It works perfect, but I am having a hard time trying to find how to set certain values to connect to the database like `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_DATABASE`, `MYSQL_USER`, and `MYSQL_PASSWORD`. This is my code:

```
final ContainerConfig containerConfig = ContainerConfig.builder()
        .hostConfig(hostConfig)
        .image(image)
        .env("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD","testrootpwd","MYSQL_DATABASE", "test", "MYSQL_USER", "test", "MYSQL_PASSWORD", "test")
        .build();

LOG.debug("Creating container for image: {}", image);
final ContainerCreation creation = this.docker.createContainer(containerConfig);
```

I am assuming that `.env` call is to set environment variables. And according to the mysql container documentation, setting those env variables is the way to do it:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

But still, I can't connect to the container, I connected to bash and I see that those env variables are not set.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I could create a dockerfile and create my own image, but I don't want to do that, I want to do it with the spotify client.

Comment: Basically, I need to do the same I can do from the terminal:

`docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_USER=test -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=test -d mysql:5.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This client uses docker API, so if the client is lacking documentation you can always check the original API.
Check the `CREATE A CONTAINER` section in [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate).

You can see that there is a JSON request example with `env` field:

```
"Env": [
           "FOO=bar",
           "BAZ=quux"
],
```

So my guess is that you can do just that in your Java code:

```
final ContainerConfig containerConfig = ContainerConfig.builder()
    .hostConfig(hostConfig)
    .image(image)
    .env("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testrootpwd", "MYSQL_DATABASE=test", ...)
    .build();
```

P.S. Also please note what the documentation says regarding this param:

> A list of environment variables to set inside the container in the
> form ["VAR=value", ...].  A variable without = is removed from the
> environment, rather than to have an empty value.

Might help you avoiding bugs later.